# Cannot link Webassessor and Trailhead accounts

Tags: trailhead, certification, webassessor

I have got email salesforce certification team to connect trailhead and weassessor accounts with a link. I have submitted my trailhead email address. But I didn't get confirmation/verification code to connect the same. I have raised a case with salesforce certification as well. Still no response. Does anyone faced this same issue?

I have followed the steps described here. http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/Link-Your-Trailhead-and-Webassessor-Accounts

Comment: You should have access to the email that's on your Trailhead account. Unfortunately, there's no way to know what your Trailhead email address is, until you reach out to support. The email on the Trailhead gets updated to the email with which you first created your Trailhead account. So if you logged in to Trailhead using your DE org, then the email on that org becomes email of Trailhead. If you don't have a way to access that email, then you need to create a new Trailhead account and merge those, and then proceed with linking to Webassessor.

Comment: @JayantDas I use my DE org to login to trailhead and I've access to that mail related to that org. But no idea why its not sending verification code/confirmation mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got resolved my issue...!!

Certified professionals who are facing the same issue can be use this approach. You need not visit unwanted articles and waste your valuable time.

Just [**log a case with salesforce certification**](http://certification.salesforce.com/open-a-case). Certification team will get in touch with you after opening the case. There may be delay of few days since there are many people who are facing the same issue, logged case for the same purpose. So be patient! Your certifications will be safe.

I thought it would be nice if I share the solution here. Thank you so much bpilling, Jayant Das, David Reed and Prasoon Kumar for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: The link is broken, in 2023.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem. I thought I had used a specific email address but wasn't receiving any confirmation emails. I then emailed trailhead@salesforce.com explaining the issue described above. They replied and told me which email I had used. Because I still had access to this email inbox I was able to proceed.

So in short, email trailhead@salesforce.com.

Comment: I have sent email to trailhead@salesforce.com and I got reply says: Trailhead Case Not Created. Your email was sent to a no-reply email address and will not be received by our team. I submitted a case with trailhead also. But no response.

Comment: It looks like they have changed the process of dealing with these issues. I read over the article again, and it no longer references this email anywhere unfortunately - it quite clearly did when I emailed them and had my issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your trailhead Account and then go to this link https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help and scroll down to click Submit a case button and follow the instructions.

Comment: The original poster states in the body of the question that they have already raised a case.

Answer (score 0):

I emailed certification@salesforce.com

The automatic reply I got was:

> **Contacting us about linking your Trailhead and Webassessor accounts?**
>   We have received a high volume of cases and are responding to them in
>   the order they are received. **If you've completed your maintenance on
>   Trailhead, don't worry, your certifications are safe from expiration.**
>   Thanks for your patience!

Although I don't know how the Webassessor certs are safe from expiring if Salesforce don't know whose Trailhead it is linked to. Maybe Salesforce won't expire any certs until they have resolved this problem.